# Adding a sequence of integers to a data frame having approx 500 rows

Tags: r, split, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with 506 rows. I am trying to achieve k-fold cross validation with linear regression model. Here is the link to my [CSV](http://www.filedropper.com/housewithmissing).

I am preparing the train and test data frame using the Leave-One-Out Model. 
I receive the following as input:

```
df - data frame with 506 records
k  - fold cross-validation (example: 10)
```

This is what I do to prepare the test and train data frames:

```
df <- c(1:506) # This is just for representation purposes
df <- cbind(idx, df)
for(ii in 1:k) {
  train <- subset.data.frame(df, df[,1] == ii)
  test <- subset.data.frame(df, df[,1] != ii)
  # Further processing with train and test datasets
}
```

This gives me a df with 5060 entries.

```
  idx  df
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   1   4
5   1   5
6   1   6
7   1   7
8   1   8
9   1   9
10  1  10
11  1  11
...
506 1 506
507 2   1
508 2   2
```

However, what I want is the data frame to be divided in to `k` equal parts:

```
   idx  df
1    1   1
2    1   2
3    1   3
4    1   4
5    1   5
6    1   6
...
48   1  48
49   1  49
50   1  50
51   1  51
52   2  52
53   2  53
54   2  54
...
504 10 504
505 10 505
506 10 506
```

I am relatively new to R. So if possible, please use a base package so I understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When it comes to running CV, I tend to create an index, using `split`, and use this index to subset the data. So for example, ..`K <- 10 ;
s <- split(sample(nrow(yourdat)), seq_len(K)) ; 
out <- lapply(s, function(ii) {
    train <- yourdat[-ii, ] ;
      test <- yourdat[ii, ] ; ... further commands })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is with your `idx` column. Here's how to create a sequence with data that will not fit perfectly in buckets. You have 506 observations that you are trying to fit in 10 buckets. Some buckets will contain more data than others.

```
df <- 1:506
idx <-ceiling(seq_along(df)/(length(df)/10))
df <- cbind(idx, df)
```

In your loop, I use `subset` because `df` is not a data.frame. Anyway, R usually figures out what type of data it deals with.

```
k <-10
for(ii in 1:k) {
  train <- subset(df, df[,1] == ii)
  test <-  subset(df, df[,1] != ii)
  # Further processing with train and test datasets
}
```

**UPDATE**

With `csv` data loaded in a `data.frame`:

```
df <-read.csv("C:/temp/house_with_missing.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)                   
idx <-ceiling(seq_along(1:nrow(df))/(nrow(df)/10))                
df <- cbind(idx, df)
```

Comment: This works with df <- 1:506. However, when I use my df, it gives the following error: 

 Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 506

Comment: Does this work? `idx <-ceiling(seq_along(1:506)/(506/10))`

Comment: I have added a URL to my csv. Hope it helps!